# How to do server side text to speech?

Tags: text-to-speech, speech-synthesis

I am building an Android and iOS app which reads jokes to users. For this, I want to do server side TTS, so that the app works in poor connectivity areas (by caching the voice content) and so that I can save on TTS calls (as the jokes will be the same for different users).

I looked at Nuance's ndev and a bunch of other TTS providers, but they all seem to have only android and iOS sdks. Is there a good TTS engine which I could use to do server side TTS?

I don't mind a paid solution also.

Answer (score 0):

Espeak is a nice command line program. It's easy to install in Linux (also runs in Windows, I think) and could be scripted with your favorite server side language: http://espeak.sourceforge.net

Comment: The voice quality seems to be pretty bad in espeak. Are you aware of utilities with better quality even if they are paid?

Comment: [The Festival Speech Synthesis System](http://www.cstr.ed.ac.uk/projects/festival/) from the University of Edinburgh is more sophisticated and easily installed in Linux. [Festvox](http://festvox.org/) from Carnegie Mellon uses Festival to craft more natural voices.